# Customized Plugin

Tags: firefox, search, plugins, opera

I want to make a plugin or extension or anything that could be attached to "Opera & firefox" to search in the current open page for built in words and give error message if something missing

e.g: "the browser will have a button, once clicked (it'll work like the normal CTRL+F but it'll have a built in words like apple & banana it'll highlight apple and banana in the text page & raise a flag or error message if apple not exist in the page )"

i'll needs also to make validations and checks on the built in words and so on but basically i want to know if the basic function could be done

just tell me how to start or what to read or which language to start learning

*P.S: i've simple programming background , i only need to know where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to look into building a browser extension.

- For Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder
- For Opera: http://dev.opera.com/extension-docs/